# using repartion in pyspark for huge set of data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql-repartition

I have a huge amount of data in a few oracle tables (the total size of data in these tables is around 50GB). I have to perform joins and perform some calculations, and these tables don't have any partitions created. I need to read this data in pyspark data frame, and finally write the CSV file into s3. It's taking a long time to run this query on the database, fetch the data and directly write to s3 (the fetched data, based on the query, is around 100MB only).
Can using `repartition` on this data frame help me in any way to improve the query performance?
Or is there any other way to make this operation faster?

Comment: What is taking long time, fetching the data from the db or writing it with spark?

Comment: Fetching the data from the database is taking a lot of time.

Comment: Do you connect with JDBC api?